# How to check if an image is converted properly to byte array in wp7

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, arrays

Currently i'm sending my image as a **byte[]** to my server, but my server is constantly replying that "Image is not attached". So how can i check if the image is properly converted to byte array??
This is the code i've used for converting the image to byte array,

```
using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(image);

                // write an image into the stream
                Extensions.SaveJpeg(btmMap, ms1,
                    image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

                // reset the stream pointer to the beginning
                ms1.Seek(0, 0);
                //read the stream into a byte array
                imageData = new byte[ms1.Length];
                ms1.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            }
```

Could anyone tell me if it works coorectly or how to check if it is working properly.
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Save it to file using `FileStream`
2. Try to open the file. If it opens properly - the problem is on server side.

Comment: :Is it a proper way to send image as a __byte[]__ to a server using HttpWebRequest??